# VBA vlookup data mismatch

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I am new to VBA, facing the following problem:

I need to return certain value, returned by IF formula, based on numeric data, kept in another worksheet. 
I have written something like this, however all the time when it comes to the point of running IF part, it gives me the error **Type mismatch**, and the problem seems to be in the values, found by vlookup. I was trying to declare it as long, variant and so on but that didn't help. However the MsgBox returnes the result from another sheet properly. Another sheet is formatted as numbers. Any ideas how to make it work?

here is the code i have for now:

```
Option Explicit
Sub find()

Dim lookup As String
Dim pkgWidth, pkgLength, pkgHeight, displaySize, AllHeaders, headerweight, itemweight, classify  As Range
Dim lastrow As Variant
Dim cl As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim widthh, lengthh, Heightt, display, Weight As Variant

'this part dynamically searches for the columns I need
Set AllHeaders = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("1:1")
Set pkgWidth = AllHeaders.find("package_width")
Set pkgLength = AllHeaders.find("package_length")
Set pkgHeight = AllHeaders.find("package_height")
Set displaySize = AllHeaders.find("display_size")


Set headerweight = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("1:1")
Set itemweight = headerweight.find("Item Weight")
Set classify = headerweight.find("AT")

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow

lookup = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
Set cl = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, classify.Column)

'here the values are being looked up from another sheet
widthh = Application.VLookup(lookup, _
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, pkgWidth.Column, False)

lengthh = Application.VLookup(lookup, _
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, pkgLength.Column, False)

Heightt = Application.VLookup(lookup, _
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, pkgHeight.Column, False)

display = Application.VLookup(lookup, _
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, displaySize.Column, False)

Weight = Application.VLookup(lookup, _
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, itemweight.Column, False)

If display > 6 Then
    If Weight < 25 Then
        cl.Value = 1.01
        Else
        cl.Value = 1.02
        End If
    Else
        If widthh >= 1970 Or lengthh >= 1970 Or Heightt >= 1970 Then
            If Weight <= 8 Then
            cl.Value = 3.01
            Else
                If Weight >= 35 Then
                cl.Value = 3.02
                Else
                cl.Value = 3.03
                End If
            End If
         Else
            If Weight <= 3 Then
            cl.Value = 5.01
            Else
                If Weight >= 8 Then
                cl.Value = 5.03
                Else
                cl.Value = 5.02
                End If
        End If
    End If
End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: (a) Insert `Option Explicit` as the first line of your code, and ensure that you explicitly declare all your variables.  (b) Assign a value to the variable `weightcol` before you use it.  (c) Use the variable `weight` instead of `weigth` (d) Are you purposely using `Application.Lookup` instead of `Application.VLookup`?

Comment: If, after you fix the code to be valid, it still gives Type Mismatch errors, let us know which line the error occurs on, and what the values are of all the variables used on that line.

Comment: What are the values of display and wieght when you step through the code just before it hits the error?

Comment: It appeared that I have an error in the worksheet with one hidden row which could not be unhidden and which values can not be read. (I don't know why) , so with on error resume next the whole stuff works. Thanks a lot, at least I found out that the code works correctly.

Comment: Note that your latest version of the code is declaring `pkgWidth`, `pkgLength`, `pkgHeight`, `displaySize`, `AllHeaders`, `headerweight` and `itemweight` to be `Variant`, and only `classify` as a `Range`

Comment: thank you, I was not aware that I have to declare everything separately. Proper declaration and getting rid of vlookups made everything work really smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `Application.VLookup` (or any of its variants) you must take into account that it can return `#N/A`, as explained in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194701.aspx):

> If lookup_value is smaller than the smallest value in the first column of table_array, `VLOOKUP` returns the #N/A error value.

If for instance `display` gets that value, then the expression `display > 6` will give you the *Type mismatch* error.

So to prevent that, either change the logic of your code so that `VLookup` is guaranteed to not return `#N/A` (if this is possible in your case, I cannot say), or test for this error value, like this:

```
If IsError(display) Then
    ' Treat the error condition...
ElseIf display > Then
    ' ...etc.
```

The same precaution may be needed for other variables that get the result of a `VLookup` call.